# wordpress Page stalls for a few seconds, then loads as normal

Tags: css, wordpress, optimization, elementor

Why in WordPress a page designed with Elementor  is not full at first and then full in a few seconds?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by using one of the following methods:

1. Define the CSS Print Method to be inline instead of using external files. This can be done by going to the Elementor > Settings > Advanced > CSS Print Method > Internal Embedding
2. The second option is to load the CSS files with an action in the functions.php file of your child theme. For example:

   ```
    if ( ! class_exists( '\Elementor\Core\Files\CSS\Post' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $template_id = 123456;
    $css_file = new \Elementor\Core\Files\CSS\Post( $template_id );
    $css_file->enqueue();}, 500 );
   ```

Instead of $template_id = 123456, enter the ID of your template, and it will always load in the site’s header. You can use this method for specific pages only.

3. Some optimization plugins can solve this as well.